# Make a copy of DOM element then add animation

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I read many articles and documentations about this but none of them seem to take the approach I'm trying to make. 
I have an array of category Items and inside it I have a nested array of said category products.
like so.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let menu of menuList">
               <ng-container *ngFor="let item of menu.catItem" >
                <div class="card" #cmp > 
                just to demonstrate
                <button class="animateIt(cmp)"> click to animate </button>
                 </div>
               </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
```

when the user click the button I would like to add some kind of animation to, I can do that without any problem but the issue is I cannot think of a way to this without using any extra JavaScript libraries.

I have tried adding ViewChildren to my component. And a function that print the element

```
 @ViewChildren('cmp') components: QueryList<ElementRef>;
 constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}
 animateIt(cmp:ElementRef){
     console.log(cmp);
     this.renderer.setAttribute(cmp.nativeElement, 'class', 'myClass'); 

                }
```

second line inside the function gives an error since cmp.nativeElement is not defined which is expected since all it does is to grab  the content of the div and just print it without making an ElementRef object.
Is there any way I can achieve this using just angular or just JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did it by using plain JS
here is the code

```
animateIt(cmp:ElementRef){

  this.el.nativeElement = cmp;
    let element = document.createElement('div');
    element = this.el.nativeElement.cloneNode(true);
    element.style.position = "absolute";
    element.style.top = this.el.nativeElement.offsetTop + 'px';
    element.style.left = this.el.nativeElement.offsetLeft + 'px';
    let parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    parent.appendChild(element);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to retrieve your element in ngAfterViewInit lifecycle, like below:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.cmp.changes.subscribe(() => {
        console.log('changed');
    })
}
```

Comment: that just gets all of them, it doesn't listen to a specific change on a single child.